# How to find a min value of a row in a specified column in a tuple - Python 2.6?

Tags: python, list, nested, tuples, min

I have a tuple in Python 2.6, details below:

```
mylist = [
['20120903', 'melon', 'shelf1', '05:31', '08:01'],
['20120903', 'melon', 'shelf1', '05:31', '14:01'],
['20120903', 'melon', 'shelf1', '05:31', '23:59'],
['20120903', 'melon', 'shelf1', '10:18', '14:01'],
['20120903', 'melon', 'shelf1', '10:18', '23:59'],
['20120904', 'melon', 'shelf1', '00:00', '14:02'],
['20120904', 'melon', 'shelf1', '05:32', '14:02'],
['20120903', 'apple', 'shelf5', '05:34', '14:02'],
['20120903', 'apple', 'shelf5', '05:34', '23:59'],
['20120904', 'apple', 'shelf5', '00:00', '14:02'],
['20120904', 'apple', 'shelf5', '05:33', '14:02']]
```

and I would like to get results like these below (when column 0, 1, 2, 3 are identical then take the minimum value of the 4-th column + when columns 0, 1, 2, 4 are identical then take the maximum value of the 3-rd column):

```
result = [
['20120903', 'melon', 'shelf1', '05:31', '08:01'],
['20120903', 'melon', 'shelf1', '10:18', '14:01'],
['20120904', 'melon', 'shelf1', '05:32', '14:02'],
['20120903', 'apple', 'shelf5', '05:34', '14:02'],
['20120904', 'apple', 'shelf5', '05:33', '14:02']]
```

Now thanks to Ashwini Chaudhary, I modified a bit his code and now it looks like this below:

```
from itertools import groupby

mylist = [
['20120903', 'melon', 'shelf1', '05:31', '08:01'],
['20120903', 'melon', 'shelf1', '05:31', '14:01'],
['20120903', 'melon', 'shelf1', '05:31', '23:59'],
['20120903', 'melon', 'shelf1', '10:18', '14:01'],
['20120903', 'melon', 'shelf1', '10:18', '23:59'],
['20120904', 'melon', 'shelf1', '00:00', '14:02'],
['20120904', 'melon', 'shelf1', '05:32', '14:02'],
['20120903', 'apple', 'shelf5', '05:34', '14:02'],
['20120903', 'apple', 'shelf5', '05:34', '23:59'],
['20120904', 'apple', 'shelf5', '00:00', '14:02'],
['20120904', 'apple', 'shelf5', '05:33', '14:02']]

step1 = []
for k1, g1 in groupby(mylist, key=lambda x1: (x1[0], x1[1], x1[2], x1[3])):
    step1.append((min(g1, key=lambda x1: map(int, x1[4].split(':')))))

step2 = []
for k2, g2 in groupby(step1, key=lambda x2: (x2[0], x2[1], x2[2], x2[4])):
    step2.append((max(g2, key=lambda x2: map(int, x2[3].split(':')))))

for result in step2:
    print result
```

Comment: What determines what is in `mylist` (the new one)?

Comment: Which one? Input list or output list?

Comment: If You want to know what is in mylist so I can only tell that a random data always within the structure: date, fruit, shelf, start_growth_time, end_growth_time

Comment: Please reopen my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need something like this:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
#filter items that contain '00:00'
>>> mylist = [x for x in mylist if x[-2] != '00:00' ]

#now group lists based on the the second last item
for k,g in groupby(mylist, key = lambda x :x [-2]):
    #find the min among the grouped lists based on the last item
    minn = min(g, key = lambda x : map(int,x[-1].split(':'))) 
    print minn
...     
['20120903', 'melon', 'shelf1', '05:31', '08:01']
['20120903', 'melon', 'shelf1', '10:18', '14:01']
['20120904', 'melon', 'shelf1', '05:32', '14:02']
['20120903', 'apple', 'shelf5', '05:34', '14:02']
['20120904', 'apple', 'shelf5', '05:33', '14:02']
```

To get a list of lists you can use a generator function:

```
from itertools import groupby
def solve(lis):
    mylist = [x for x in lis if x[-2] != '00:00' ]
    for k,g in groupby(mylist, key = lambda x :x [-2]):
            #find the min among the grouped lists based on the last item
            minn = min(g, key = lambda x : map(int,x[-1].split(':'))) 
            yield minn
...         
>>> list(solve(mylist))
[['20120903', 'melon', 'shelf1', '05:31', '08:01'],
 ['20120903', 'melon', 'shelf1', '10:18', '14:01'],
 ['20120904', 'melon', 'shelf1', '05:32', '14:02'],
 ['20120903', 'apple', 'shelf5', '05:34', '14:02'],
 ['20120904', 'apple', 'shelf5', '05:33', '14:02']]
```

Comment: You are my G.O.D.! How did you know how to find a reference point? Thanks so much! It works great!

Comment: @constantine It was pretty much guessable :). Feel free to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-paccepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it worked for you.