# Get min int in a list of tuples of (int, string) in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I want to extract from a list of tuples `(int, string)` the `string` value of the tuple with minimum `int`.

For example, if I have this list:

```
l = [('a', 5), ('b', 3), ('c', 1), ('d', 6)]
```

The output should be 'c', because the minimum integer is in the tuple `('c', 1)`.

I've tried different things, none worked so far. Thanks.

Comment: `I've tried different things, none worked so far.` post an attempt from that.

Comment: Well, I've tried the answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468923/how-to-find-a-min-value-of-a-row-in-a-specified-column-in-a-tuple-python-2-6 but couldn't understand what was happening and adapt it to my case, and also, tried with the `zip` and `map` functions as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002796/python-find-the-min-max-value-in-a-list-of-tuples

Comment: Try this

    l = [('a', 5), ('b', 3), ('c', 1), ('d', 6)]
    
    p=[min(l[i]) for i in range(len(l))]
    
    l[p.index(min(p))]

using list index and

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a dictionary since you list of tuple looks a lot like it: `d = dict(l)` then `min(d, key=d.get)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [min()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) function with a key lambda:

```
min_tuple = min(l, key=lambda x:x[1])
```

This makes use of the min function which returns the minimum element on an iterable. An inline lambda function is used, which is a kind of comparator of tuple elements, so I'm returning as the key the second item of the tuple (the int). So when the min function is executed using this key function the minimum tuple is the one containing the minimum integer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `min()` for this:

```
In [1]: l = [('a', 5), ('b', 3), ('c', 1), ('d', 6)]

In [2]: min(l, key=lambda t:t[1])
Out[2]: ('c', 1)
```